# Getting script url from php

Tags: php

I have a PHP file (`mymainfile.php`)

inside this PHP file, i have include some other PHP files (`include.php`).

The URL is:

http://www.domain.com/my/mymainfile.php

Now i want to get the URL into a variable inside the `include.php` file.

All my tries with the `$_SERVER` variables will give me "`domain.com/my/include.php`" back and that's not what I'm looking for.

Is it possible, and if it's, how?

Comment: please provide some code for us to understand the question better

Comment: Did you try `_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]`

Comment: Here's a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php)

Comment: $actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; - that wont solve my problem - like i wrote, the result is not "mymainfile.php" the result is the "include.php" file:..!?

Comment: Use `__FILE__` instead. It contains the path of the currently executed PHP context.

Comment: I'm sorry, but __FILE__ gives me the path of the included file, too !?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  getcwd()? http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php
Or `dirname(__FILE__) (or just __FILE__ )`
Aand 1 more try

```
function get_file_dir() {
    global $argv;
    return realpath($argv[0]);
}
```